# Fan-Gate on Facebook App url + Facebook Tab Display Blank

Tags: facebook, tabs, fan-page

I have a problem on Facebook App.
I want to make a fan-gate when any one enter the app url, Ex. apps.facebook.com/zoomcompetition/

I can't make it on the tab because it display blank.
but it works on the app url so I want to add fan-gate on the app appoint to Facebook Page.
This is the code

```
<?php

require 'src/facebook.php';
//require 'fbconfig.php';
require 'functions.php';

// Create An instance of our Facebook Application.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => ***************,
'secret' => **************,
));

// Get the app User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
try {
// If the user is authenticated and logged-in
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
//var_dump($user_profile);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}

// If the user is authenticated then generate the variable for the logout URL
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

?>

<!-- Insert Logged in HTML here -->
 <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>


 <?php
//Always place this code at the top of the Page

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

// Redirection to login page  facebook

header("location: index.php");

}
echo ' Welcome '.$_SESSION['username'];  // or whatever you want your user to see.


$varri = "http://www.*****.ps";  
?>  

  <iframe src=<?php print $varri; ?> scrolling="auto" width=100% height=100% frameborder="0"> </iframe>


<?php
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) { 
 $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                      'link' => 'https://www.************.com',

                                      'picture' => 'http://www.*******************.jpg',
                                      'caption' => "أهلا وسهلا!",

                                      'message' => ' Welcome '.$_SESSION['username'],


                                      'uid'=> $facebook->getUser()
                                 ));
}


?>


<?php
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}


if (!empty($user_profile )) {

$username = $user_profile['name'];

$uid = $user_profile['id'];

$email = $user_profile['email'];

$user = new User();

$userdata = $user->checkUser($uid, 'facebook', $username,$email,$twitter_otoken,$twitter_otoken_secret);

if(!empty($userdata)){ 
session_start();

$_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];

$_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;

$_SESSION['username'] = $userdata['username'];

$_SESSION['email'] = $email;

$_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $userdata['oauth_provider'];

//header("Location: home.php");
?>
<!--<!DOCTYPE>
<HTML>
<head>
<script> 
function run(){
    window.location.href = '/facebook/home.php';
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="run()">
</body>
</html> -->
<?php
}

} else {

die("There was an error."); 
}

}

else {
// Generate a session if there is none.

$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => ' read_stream, publish_stream, email'));
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<HTML>
<head>
<script> 
function run(){
    window.location.href = '<?php echo $login_url ?>';
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="run()">
</body>
</html>
<?php

}

?>
```

Can you help me to solve one of the following:

1. What do I need to make it not display "Blank" on the tab?
   2- How can I make a fan-gate for specific Facebook Pae if any one go to App
   url directly?

Answer (score 0):

> What do I need to make it not display "Blank" on the tab?

Generate some output instead of nothing, I’d guess …?

> How can I make a fan-gate for specific Facebook Pae if any one go to App url directly?

You can redirect from the canvas page to a specific page/app combination via JavaScript (top.location.href = "FB-Address of your page/app id combo"). And to check whether you’re on the canvas page, the simplest way to do so is give it an extra GET parameter in the canvas page address, which you then can evaluate in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but where can I add the output code to display on Tabs?? I added the following code to display on tabs (also you can find it on the full code above) but it display bank:
`echo ' Welcome '.$_SESSION['username'];  // or whatever you want yeour user to see.


$varri = "http://www.*****.ps";  
?>  
`
Where can I add the code of redirect in my code??